# Is there anyway to shorten this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am a Javascript beginner, I am trying to make the rock paper scissor game as a beginner practice project. I wrote a piece of code to assign the move of the player. I have three buttons on the page for the respektive moves

[image: As shown in this Image]

Here is the code that i wrote to assign the value to the variable of Player move-

```
const paper =document.getElementById('paper');
const scissor = document.getElementById('scissor')
const rock = document.getElementById('rock')

paper.addEventListener('click', function (){movePlayer = "paper"; })
rock.addEventListener('click', function (){movePlayer = "rock"; })
scissor.addEventListener('click', function (){movePlayer = "scissor";})
```

The ID rock, paper, scissor are for the respective buttons.

I feel that there is a shorter way to do this.
This my first time on Stack Overflow

Comment: Well, there's [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: `movePlayer = this.id`

Answer (score 3):

*SO* normally does not do code review. But here you are

```
['paper','scissor','rock'].forEach(hand => document.getElementById(hand) 
  .addEventListener('click', function() { movePlayer = this.id }));
```

but why not delegate?

```js
let movePlayer;
const showMove = () => console.log(movePlayer);


document.getElementById("handContainer").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("hand")) {
    movePlayer = tgt.id;
    showMove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="handContainer">
  <div class="hand" id="paper">Paper</div>
  <div class="hand" id="scissors">Scissors</div>
  <div class="hand" id="rock">Rock</div>
  <div class="hand" id="lizard">Lizard</div>
  <div class="hand" id="spock">Spock</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array and a loop:

```
for (const type of ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]) {
    document.getElementById(type).addEventListener("click", () => {
        movePlayer = type;
    });
}
```

Or `forEach`, which is also a loop, just a less obvious one.

---

Side note: It's usually "scissors" rather than "scissor."

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to your `div` elements click event. then in your click function get the element `id` and set `movePlayer` like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    movePlayer = this.id
   })  
})
```

Edit: You can assign a class to your elements and use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` either

Comment: That will listen to ALL divs on the page, regardless of what they signify AND add unnecessary eventlisteners to irrelevant divs.

Answer (score 0):

Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) springs to mind

```
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const origin = evt.target.closest("#rock, #paper, #scissor");
  if (origin) { movePlayer = origin.id; }
});
```

**Demo**:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const origin = evt.target.closest("#rock, #paper, #scissor");
  if (origin) {
    movePlayer = origin.id;
    // for demo
    const picked = document.querySelector(".picked");
    const movePlayerId = document.querySelector(".movePlayer");
    picked && picked.classList.remove("picked");
    movePlayerId && movePlayerId.classList.remove("movePlayer");
    origin.firstChild.classList.add("picked");
    origin.classList.add("movePlayer");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.picked {
  border-color: red;
}

div.movePlayer:after {
  content: ' > movePlayer now: 'attr(id);
  color: green;
}

span {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="paper"><span>Paper</span></div>
<div id="scissor"><span>Scissor</span></div>
<div id="rock"><span>Rock</span></div>
```